# How to manage State values when cursor is moving fast over a component in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-state-management

I am trying to set state value when cursor is over a component or not.

```
toggleIcon = () => {
        this.setState({ isMouseOver: !this.state.isMouseOver });
    };

...

<div
     onMouseEnter={() => this.toggleIcon()}
     onMouseLeave={() => this.toggleIcon()}
>
    {isMouseOver ? (
                    <InfoIcon />
                ) : (
                    <NormalIcon />
                )}
</div>
```

When I move cursor over that component in normal speed, it works well.

But If I move cursor fast, only `onMouseEnter` event is triggered but not `onMouseLeave` event. 
By the way, `InfoIcon` is not changing to `NormalIcon` even the cursor is not over that component.

If there's no state management in `toggleIcon` function,both events are triggered even if cursor is moving fast over the component.

Please teach me what is wrong and how can I fix it.
Thanks. :)

Comment: Please check correct answer

Comment: not found correct answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :hover effect to change background image.

Answer (score 1):

Trying explicitly passing the state you want instead of toggling it.

```
toggleIcon = isMouseOver => this.setState({ isMouseOver });
...
onMouseEnter={() => this.toggleIcon(true)}
onMouseExit={() => this.toggleIcon(false)}
```

Comment: I tried in your method, but it is not working well.   : (

Comment: I tried it before. but I couldn't see the result I want.

Comment: Ok, well both of my solutions should work for the code you've provided.  Can you try to recreate your issue in a snippet here?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const NormalIcon = () => (<div> Normal </div>)
const InfoIcon = () => (<div> Info </div>)

class Thing extends React.Component {
  state = { isMouseOver: false };
  
  toggleIcon = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ isMouseOver: !prevState.isMouseOver }));
  render = () => {
    const { isMouseOver } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div
        onMouseEnter={this.toggleIcon}
        onMouseLeave={this.toggleIcon}
      >
        {isMouseOver ? <InfoIcon /> : <NormalIcon />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Thing />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Looks to be working as expected.  I changed your `setState` in `toggleIcon` to use a function instead of an object, but other than that, it seems fine...

Comment: Please check this [cl.ly/0c47ed437b3a]

Comment: Hi @larz, I solved this issue by using display: none and display: block in CSS.